# This recursive program is giving different output every single time

Tags: recursion, permutation

I came upon an algorithm for generating permutations of a set in a book by Michael Goodrich.

```
def puzzle(k,S,U):
    for e in U:
        S.append(e)
        U.remove(e)
        if k == 1:
            print(S)
        else:
            puzzle(k-1,S,U)
        U.add(e)
        S.pop()
k = 3
S = []
U = {'a','b','c'}
print(puzzle(k,S,U))
```

Interestingly enough this program is giving me different output with the same input can anyone explain me why is it behaving like that and what can I change to make this algorithm work ?

Comment: I guess because U is an unordered set, so you never know in which order the elements will be processed inside of the loop

Comment: Okay thank you for your response i think the whole problem is because U is an unordered set that's explains the weird output I am getting everytime